# 1 Dimensional Array, Multiples of 5. Stuck on a few. New to coding

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is the assignment:

> Write a program that assigns and stores the first 20 multiples of 5 in the array called Data, no other array can be used in the program. The program should output the elements of the array, according to the following:

a) write only the commands to assign and store the values in Data

b) output the array: 10 numbers/line with the sum of each line

c) output the array: in reversed order, 5 numbers/line with the sum for each line

d) the odd indexed position values (Data[1], Data[3], Data[5],...), 5 values/line and their sum

e) the even indexed position values (Data[3], Data[4], Data[6],...), 5 values/line and their sum

This is my code:

```
   //** TASK 4

 //a,b
int data[]=new int[21]; int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
        data[i]=5*i;
        sum+= data[i];
        if(i%11==0)
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("sum " + sum);


//  int a[]=new int[21];
  //    for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
  //     a[i]=5*i;
  //    //System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
  //            }
  //        System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    //c
    int sum2=0;
    for(int i=data.length-2;i>0;i--){
        data[i]+=5;
        sum2+= data[i];
        if(i%5==0)
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
   }
    System.out.println("sum " + sum2);

    System.out.println();

    //d
   int sum3=0;
   for(int i=1;i<21;i=i+2){
           data[i]=5*i;
           sum3+= data[i];
           if(i%11==0)
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("sum " + sum3);
    System.out.println();

   //e
    int sum4=0;
    for(int i=2;i<21;i=i+2){
        data[i]=5*i;
        sum4+= data[i];
        if(i%5==0)
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("sum " + sum4);
```

This is the output:
For a/b)

```
    5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 
    55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95 100 sum 1050
```

- I dont know how to seperate my a and b code

For c)

```
    100 95 90 85 
    80 75 70 65 60 
    55 50 45 40 35 
    30 25 20 15 10 sum 1045
```

- for c i am getting 4 numbers in the first line, i dont know why

For d)

```
    5 15 25 35 45 
    55 65 75 85 95 sum 500
```

- I have this right

For e)

```
   10 20 30 40 
   50 60 70 80 90 
   100 sum 550
```

- it is not letting me have 5 numbers per line

***I dont know how to put the sum for each line for all of the parts of this assignment.
My teacher did not teach us how and wont help up and i am so confused. Please help. I have been trying to figure it out for so long

- he wants it to start from 5 not 0

Comment: @Stefan http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "It is okay to ask about homework". It's not like OP is trying to hide the fact it is homework, and there is some code here to show that some effort has been made.

Comment: Maybe you're just blocked by the wrong assumption that you need to implement a) and b) in one go. If you just follow the assignment step by step it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Filburt I have tried. Been stuck on it for days

Comment: Perhaps instead of an array of `int[21]` and `for i = 1...20` you make the array of `int[20]`, start the `for` loop at 0, and multiply 5 by `i + 1` each iteration. It would just be neater code by most standards, and use slightly less memory in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give the answer here, being a homework assignment I believe the process is more important than the result. However I'll try to guide as well as I can.

The first thing I notice is that the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class is extremely useful here.

As @Filburt pointed out: Try to do this one part at a time.

Starting with a: Try to get used to the fact that the first index is 0, then just iterate over the 20 elements and make their value what you want: `(i+1)*5`

b: Here modulus and the `StringBuilder` comes in handy. What you are looking to do is something like iterating over all `data[i]` then appending `data[i] + " "` to the string builder, at the same time setting a running sum of the value.

Since you want to add the sum and a new line every 10 entries a useful thing to know is that `i%10` for the 20 values is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

So when you get to the 10th element, `9` you want to add the sum to the `StringBuilder` and a new line character (`"\r\n"`on windows, `"\n"` on Unix/MacOSX) and set the sum back to 0.

At the end you can simply print the stringbuilder and voila!

c: Same as the previous, really, just iterating backwards, and a modulus of 5 going `4, 3, 2, 1, 0, ...` (meaning you add the sum on 0 ).

d & e: This is actually identical with b, but only printing every other entry, where `i%2 == 1` and `i%2 == 0` in that order. So just make sure only to append to the stringbuilder when this is true and all should be fine.

Hoping this helps without being too obvious.

Comment: I haven't learned StringBuilder so i'm quiet confused as to what you are saying. Thank you for the help though

Comment: Since it's a homework and you're new at coding then forget (by now) `StringBuilder` but consider reading and trying it yourself whenever you can. You still can use `String myString = string1 + string2 + ...;` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should be posting this, but here you go anyway:

```
    // Part (a)
    int data[] = new int[21];
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++){
        data[i]=5*i;
    }

    // Part (b)
    int sum=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++){
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        sum+= data[i];

        if(i%10==0)
        {
           System.out.println(" Sum: " + sum);
           sum = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Part (c)
    int sum2=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++){
        System.out.print(data[21-i] + " ");
        sum2+= data[21-i];

        if(i%5==0)
        {
            System.out.println(" Sum: " + sum2);
            sum2 = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Part (d)
    int sum3=0;
    for(int i= 2; i < 22; i = i+2){
        System.out.print(data[i-1] + " ");
        sum3+= data[i-1];

        if(i % 10 == 0){
            System.out.println(" Sum: " + sum3);
            sum3 = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Part (e)
    int sum4=0;
    for(int i=2;i<21;i=i+2){
        System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        sum4+= data[i];

        if(i % 10==0){
            System.out.println(" Sum: " + sum4);
            sum4 = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is what you need, I think.

Comment: You are welcome! If this solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted so that your question will stop showing in unanswered questions.